# I've just deleted the message OR I just deleted the message

Tags: american-english, present-perfect, simple-past

**Context:** I was talking informally on WhatsApp and wrote the following:

> I was about to send you a "grammatical stuff", and that's when it hit
> me: "She's already studying a lot of things." That's why **I've just
> deleted the message** above.

Can I use **present perfect** here, or should I use **simple past**?

Comment: You’re far more likely to say “have just done” in BrE and “just did” in AmE. I actually did some research on this at some point...

Comment: What do you mean?  If you, in the recent past, deleted the message then it's best expressed as "I've".  If you saw the message and chose to ignore it then "I" will work, though you probably should use a different wording to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: You can hear both forms in both varieties. It’s a matter of frequency, a tendency, not a strict a rule.

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct.But the Britishers say  I have just deleted the message while The Americans say I just deleted the message
Even in India we say I have just deleted the message because we follow the British more than the Americans while writing formally
In competitive Exams we strictly follow the British English

Comment: I regret to inform you that this pondian matter is not at all so locked in as you would allege here.

Comment: @tchrist.don't you agree that the British use present perfect and the Americans simple past when just is used an adverb?

Comment: That's correct. I do not agree, and I have just said as much.

Answer (score -2):

Both work. If you want it more formal though I would use the second one you mentioned " I just deleted the message".

Comment: That may be "more formal" in AmE. It certainly isn't more formal in BrE.